# For loop issue - javascript - php - google maps

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, loops

I'm using this for loop in javascript and I'm trying to create polygons on a google map with data retrieved from database. my problem here is that i have included php inside the javascript and each time the for loop runs the value of $i is never changed. anyone can help??

```
enter code here

<?php $i  = 0 ?>;
for(i =0; i< <?=$length?>; i++)
{

        var coordinates = "<?=$districtsarray[$i]['coords']?>";
        var coordinates = coordinates.substr(1, coordinates.length-2).split("),(");
        var souniCoordinates = coordinates.map(function(pointString){
            var latlon = pointString.split(", ");
            return  new google.maps.LatLng(latlon[0], latlon[1]);
        });

        var SouniCoords = [souniCoordinates];

    <?php echo $districtsarray[$i]['name']?> = new google.maps.Polygon({
        paths: SouniCoords,
        strokeColor: '#383838 ',
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: '#CD5C5C ',
        fillOpacity: 0.5
    });
    <?php echo $districtsarray[$i]['name']?>.setMap(map);
    <?php $i=$i+1;?>

}
</script>

<?php
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion mixing PHP and JavaScript like this makes code hard to read and maintain. I would recommend using the PHP function json_encode (http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to convert your PHP data structure into JSON and echo it out in one place.

Then use JSON.parse() https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse to convert the string into a JavaScript object.

So it might look something like this:

```
var data = JSON.parse(<?php echo json_encode($data); ?>);
```

Then only use JavaScript after this point :).

Answer (score 0):

step 1) take value of php variable into a javascript variable like this

```
var javascriptarray = JSON.parse('< json_encode($districtsarray); ?>');
```

step 2) now use  "`javascriptarray`" & javascript variable  `"i"` in loop to access its elements like this

```
var coordinates = javascriptarray[i]['coords'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, please understand that the above is bad practice as it makes maintenance/debugging somewhere between awkward and impossible. If you are insistent on doing so, a better alternative would be to use string interpolation:

```
<?php
echo <<< END
//always use K&R style for js because of automatic ; insertion:
for (var i=0, i < $length, i++) {
    //do stuff
}
END
?>
```

The way you have written it 'i' has no definition in javascript, incrementing undefined does not have a meaningful result. Because of these kinds of problems you should not mix javascript and php like this. A better alternative is:

```
$.getJSON('myPHP.php', function(response) {
    var data = JSON.parse(response);
    for (index in data) {
        var row = data[index]
        //do stuff
    }
})
```

This uses jquery although it is certainly possible to achieve this with raw js, it just takes more code. Have the php script 'myPHP' return an array with the records from the db.